# Do the Dead Sea scrolls describe any prophecy which was fulfilled after they were written?

Tags: prophecy, dead-sea-scrolls

Is there any manuscript among the Dead Sea scrolls, which foretold something that happened after the manuscript was written?

Comment: Do you mean aside from the Biblical books found among them?  Otherwise the answer is a bit too obvious, as Caleb has already pointed out.

Comment: @Mason: Among the Biblical books.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes!

The Dead Sea Scrolls are not themselves a unique set of content, but rather a collection --rather like someone's private library-- of various texts from the time period that were all preserved together and help us understand the state of those texts at a specific point in time.

One example would be the [Isaiah scroll](http://dss.collections.imj.org.il/isaiah), a basically complete copy of the entire book of Isaiah in one place. The book of Isiah was written ~750 years before Christ and includes many specific descriptions of what is life, dead and resurrection would be like.

> **[Isaiah 53:7-9](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Isaiah+53:7-9/)** (ESV)
>   He was oppressed, and he was afflicted,
>   yet he opened not his mouth;
>   like a lamb that is led to the slaughter,
>   and like a sheep that before its shearers is silent,
>   so he opened not his mouth.
>   By oppression and judgment he was taken away;
>   and as for his generation, who considered
>   that he was cut off out of the land of the living,
>   stricken for the transgression of my people?
>   And they made his grave with the wicked
>   and with a rich man in his death,
>   although he had done no violence,
>   and there was no deceit in his mouth.

You can see these verses [on the scroll here](http://dss.collections.imj.org.il/isaiah#53:7). If you are interested there are lots of commentaries available on the hundreds of specific things Isaiah foretold about the Messiah that were fulfilled in the person of Jesus.

Also be aware that other works besides canonical scriptural texts were among the scrolls found. There are other works from the time period. The find has no particular affect on what text are or are not considered scripture any more than looking at the titles in a pastor's library today would prove one way or another what he believed, but the quality and quantity of texts found together do provide collaborative evidence for the integrity of other copies of the texts that were found elsewhere and in smaller chunks.

Comment: Thanks! That's the kind of prophecy I was looking for. I would really like to have something like the fall of Babylon in there, but the Dead Sea scrolls seem to have been written after the fact.

Comment: 1 Peter 2 says the Suffering Servant had its fulfillment in Jesus: "For what glory is it, if committing sin, and being buffeted for it, you endure? But if doing well you **suffer** patiently; this is thankworthy before God. For unto this are you called: because Christ also **suffered** for us, leaving you an example that you should follow his steps. *Who did no sin, neither was guile found in his mouth.*  ..

Comment: ..Who, when he was reviled, did not revile: when he suffered, he threatened not: but delivered himself to him that judged him unjustly. Who his own self bore our sins in his body upon the tree: that we, being dead to sins, should live to justice: *by whose stripes you were healed.* For you were as *sheep going astray;* but you are now converted to the shepherd and overseer of your souls."

Answer (score 3):

Yes again!

"They have pierced my hands and my feet." - Psalm 22v16.

Admittedly, this verse will be argued against by Jews and unbelievers until the last day, but here goes:-

The Hebrew Masoretic text was produced by Jews several hundred years after the time of Christ (and who, of course, did not accept Jesus of Nazareth as their Messiah).  The (English translation of the) Masoretic Text Psalm 22 verse 16 says:-
"Like a lion are my hands and my feet."

On the other hand the Jewish producers of the Septuagint, the Greek translation of the Old Testament, translated before the time of Christ by Jews in Egypt had translated it:-
"They have dug my hands and my feet."  The word "dug" can be understood as "dug through" or "pierced".

The Septuagint was needed because many Jews in the diaspora had Greek as their first language.  Hebrew was falling/had largely fallen into disuse, not just because of Greek but also because of Aramaic.

There is a subtle difference between the Hebrew words for "like a lion" and "they have pierced" - the left most letter is different.  In one it ends [Hebrew reads right to left] with the longer letter vav (ו) rather than the shorter yod (י), giving כארו ka'aru. This is not a currently recognised word in the Hebrew language, but without the aleph it becomes כרו, "dug", "mined", or "excavated".

It is true that the Hebrew word for "they have pierced", with the aleph included, is not used elsewhere in the Old Testament and it is difficult therefore to be certain of translation: but the point for me is that the translators of the Septuagint had no motive for misrepresenting the translation of the Hebrew, and in addition were very likely better at OT Hebrew than the Masoretic Jews, who were mostly around about 500 to 1000 CE (AD), and far better at ancient Hebrew than modern Hebrew speakers and scholars who argue against their translation.  What the Septuagint translators seem to be essentially saying is that the inclusion of the aleph in the Hebrew word represents a variant spelling.

When the Dead Sea Scrolls became available it was naturally of major interest what the left most letter would be. The DSS are arguably the most important archaeological find for Bible students, but they can also be very frustrating: very often there is just a fragment of a text, and we can know the full text once existed, but cannot know the precise wording of the text because 'time' has caused the bit we really want to know about to rot away or fade.  Would the DSS contain a clear reading of Psalm 22 verse 16?

I quote from "The Dead Sea Scrolls Bible - The Oldest Known Bible Translated for the First Time into English", translated and with commentary by Martin Abegg Jr, Peter Flint & Eugene Ulrich,  HarperCollins, 1999 :-

> Among the scrolls the reading in question is found only in the Psalms scroll found at Nahal Hever (abbreviated 5/6HevPs), which reads "They have pierced my hands and my feet"!

When you read Psalm 22 it is clear to all who are believers that it is a prophecy concerning the death of the Messiah.

So there you have it: the Dead Sea Scrolls predict not just that the Messiah would die, they predict also the manner of death his death, that he would die by crucifixion.

Post Script

It is almost invariably stated with great authority as fact that the Dead Sea Scrolls do not contain anything from the New Testament.  But this is not correct.  The evidence presented back in 1972 needs to be presented again, sifted and summed up.

In the earliest discoveries at Qumran there wasn't any NT discoveries.  But, later, cave 7 was discovered and it was obvious that the writing on the tiny portions of papyrus were Greek.

In March 1972, papyrologist Father Jose O'Callaghan announced his work and argued that one of the fragments, 7Q5 is a copy of Mark 6:52,53; another fragment is of Mark 4:28; another of 1 Timothy 3:16 to 4:3; another of Mark 12:17; another might be James 1:23,24, another Mark 6:48, Romans 5:11,12, Acts 27:38, 2 Peter 1:15.

Some of these identifications are based on very few greek letters, and the positioning of these letters on the papyrus fragment and our knowledge of lengths of lines of Greek text for the NT parchments.  But it seems the identification of Mark 6:52,53 and 1 Tim 3:16-4:3 (7Q4) are certain.

> For Albert Dou, professor of mathematics at the University of Madrid and a member of the Royal Academy of Sciences, the possibility that 7Q5 is not identical to verses 52-53 of chap. 6 of Mark’s gospel, is 1 in 900 billion(!)

See https://christianpublishinghouse.co/2020/06/14/7q4-and-7q5-cave-7-of-qumran-dead-sea-manuscripts-are-they-fragments-of-the-gospel-of-mark-and-1-timothy/

The best way I know of that the reader can get a picture of the evidence is the book "The first New Testament" by David Estrada and William White Jr. An alternative, though not as good, the "The Jesus Papyrus" by Carsten Thiede and Matthew D'Ancora.

Comment: https://christianpublishinghouse.co/2020/06/14/7q4-and-7q5-cave-7-of-qumran-dead-sea-manuscripts-are-they-fragments-of-the-gospel-of-mark-and-1-timothy/

Comment: @Betho's - Thanks so much.  I will add some further info to the answer from your linked article.